# biblatex with numeric-comp doesn't compress

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to use the numeric-comp style of biblatex to produce cites like [1-3]. Unfortunately, all I ever get is [1, 2, 3]. Any ideas what could be the problem?

A minimal tex-file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\begin{document}
MadAnalysis \cite{madanalysis2013, madanalysis2014, madanalysis2015}
\end{document}
```

and my (reduced) bibliography looks like this:

```
@article{madanalysis2013,
    author          = {E. Conte and B. Fuks and G. Serret},
    title           = {MadAnalysis~5, a user-friendly framework for collider phenomenology},
    journal         = {Comput. Phys. Commun.},
    year            = {2013},
    volume          = {184},
    number          = {1}
}
@article{madanalysis2014,
    author          = {E. Conte and B. Dumont and B. Fuks and C. Wymant},
    title           = {Designing and recasting LHC analyses with MadAnalysis~5},
    journal         = {Eur. Phys. J. C},
    year            = {2014},
    volume          = {74},
    number          = {10}
}
@article{madanalysis2015,
    author          = {B. Dumont and B. Fuks and S. Kraml and S. Bein and Weitere},
    title           = {Toward a public analysis database for LHC new physics searches using MADANALYSIS~5},
    journal         = {Eur. Phys. J. C},
    year            = {2015},
    volume          = {75},
    number          = {2}
}
```

Running pdflatex, biber, pdflatex (Texlive 2015, Biber 2.1) however produces only:

[image: MadAnalysis [1, 2, 3]]

Comment: Adding the option `citestyle=numeric-comp` should work. B.t.w. you should update to `biber 2.4`  and `biblatex 3.3`.

Comment: Or simply write `style=numeric-comp` for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes from writing only `bibstyle=numeric-comp` as an option. If you want to compress also citations, you have to add `citestyle=numeric-comp`, or better, if you want it for both, simply `style=numeric-comp`.

Comment: Indeed `bibstyle=numeric-comp` is equivalent to `bibstyle=numeric` and as such changes nothing from the default (`style=numeric`).